# How to communicate to AWS EC2 instance from a Private Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I want to monitor the performance of an application hosted on AWS from the monitoring tool present in a Private Cloud.

What are the various steps that are needed to be followed to establish a successful connection between the private cloud and the Amazon cloud?

Comment: When you say private cloud are you talking about amazon VPC? or an environment outside of aws?

Comment: To add to the questions, what monitoring tool are you talking about?

Comment: @datasage : An environmaent outside of aws.

Comment: @Guy : BMC ProactiveNet Performance Monitor

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your EC2 instances are not inside of Amazon VPC then EC2 security groups control just inbound connection. So if you need to connect from your VPC to the EC2 your need to open necessary port in EC2 security group.

Another option, if you don't want to open ports on ec2 security groups you can use SNS for communication between EC2 and VPC. For instance, your ec2 puts messages to SNS.The SNS puts message to SQS queue. The service on VPC time to time pull messages from SQS and process theirs in your monitoring tool.

Comment: actually i want to connect AWS to an environment completely outside AWS. A different private cloud all together.

Answer (score 1):

Basicall the AWS cloud is like any other network(or servers) you build. So to connect to it for SNMP monitoring you would open SNMP port(161 and 162) in the security group. So basically you would edit the inbound rule and add udp port 161 and 162 for the security group of the AWS server where the application is. But again the servers you build also need changine the firewal configurations. On linux servers you would also need to edit iptables to allow such traffic, Windows has its firewall settings and so forth. But as the others have said you may want to provide deatils such the monitoring tool you are using, etc.